# How to save multiple arrays into a single arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to save the generated arraylist from my loop into a separate arraylist. It won't allow me to do it; I'm getting an error:

```
public static void ranCentroid() {
        Random randomPoint = new Random();
        Cent = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCen; i++) {
            int randomP = randomPoint.nextInt(Points.size());
            System.out.println(Points.get(randomP));
            Cent.get(i).add(randomP);
        }
        System.out.println(Cent);

    }
```

Getting Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at phase1.Main.ranCentroid(Main.java:100)
    at phase1.Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

Comment: An array is not the same thing as an `ArrayList`.  Which are you working with?  It makes rather a large difference to what you need to do.

Comment: an ArrayList ...

Comment: `Cent` is still empty, so `get` will not work... need to add some (`numCen`) new lists to it first - Also would be nice to use `array` for arrays (`...[]`) and not for lists, confusing a lot of people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that Points is a list, because you call the methods `Points.size()` and `Points.get(x)`. To summarize your results declare a new list and use the method `List.addAll` :

```
public static void ranCentroid() {
    Random randomPoint = new Random();
    List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numCen; i++) {
        int randomP = randomPoint.nextInt(Points.size());
        result.addAll(Points.get(randomP));            
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need a list of lists as a result:

```
public static void ranCentroid() {
    Random randomPoint = new Random();
    List<List<Double>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numCen; i++) {
        int randomP = randomPoint.nextInt(Points.size());
        result.add(Points.get(randomP));            
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: This makes every element into a single element and does not keep their array structue.

Comment: @Ant I don't get your point. May be it's easier if you show an example input of your list `Points` and the expected out put.

Comment: @Ant see my edit if you need a list of lists as a result.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is a reducing function. A reducing function takes a collection and reduces it one step down. So in this case a 2D array into a 1D array.

You can also do it without the built-in reducing function by creating an array list, and looping over your elements and adding it to the array list you created.